# How to loop through all the referrer urls in Local storage?

Tags: javascript

I have three different Urls displayed in the local storage. This happens upon clicking on the radio button for paypal express checkout. I want to access the second url `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com` but unfortunately, the code that I have written below will loop only for the first one `https//master.....`. Can anyone please guide me on how do I access the second/third url in a local storage.

**Code that I have for looping Local storage -**

```
Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
console.log(`${key} => ${value}`); })
```

**Local storage screenshot -**

[image]

Comment: you cannot access localstorage for different host.

Comment: Hi @uingtea - Is there any way to perform it? Sorry I am bit new to this so wanted some help and guidance

Comment: use extension [storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)

Comment: The documentation reads... _"The **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** read-only property of the `window` interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin)(*1); the stored data is saved across browser sessions."_ ...where (*1) _**origin**_ is described as ... _"Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match"_